# Eclipse won't open after crashing

Tags: eclipse

This is my second time my Eclipse has crashed and I get the same error as the first time where it gives the "workspace is in use" window. The first time I fixed it by deleting a workbench file. This time it didn't work. I researched and tried suggestions online to delete other files and they didn't work either. Other than deleting Eclipse and reinstalling, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: No need to delete Eclipse, using a new workspace will do!

Comment: I would do that but my workspace is connected to my professor's SVN, so I can't create a new workspace last minute.